# nodeValue not returning text

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript. I am using nodeValue to return text from a node. Since, it was returning null, I tried with firstChild.nodeValue. But, now it says: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null
Here's the code: -

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="get.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="eventsList">
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Linked item to Google</a></li>
    <li>List 4</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

get.js: -

```
window.onload=function hear()
{
    var no=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    var msg="";
    if (no.hasChildNodes())
    {
        var son=no.childNodes;
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<son.length;i++)
          msg+=son[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
    alert(msg);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Gramercy...

Comment: `childNodes` returns text and comments as well, and not all your childnodes have a `firstChild`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h6nbno73/

Comment: Thanx for your reply....I would like to clarify one thing. Isn't "List 1" the firstChildNode of the first tag "li"?

Gramercy...

Comment: According to the link of jsfiddle, you used textContent in place of nodeValue. Can you explain to me the difference?

Gramery...

Comment: For an element node, `nodeValue` doesn't return anything, you have to use `textContent`. You can see what it returns on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)

Comment: According to MDN, nodeValue returns text if the content is text. For example, if I have <p>Hello</p> in body and the js has

var no=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var msg=no.firstChild.nodeValue;
alert(msg);

I see "Hello" in the alert box. But, I don't understand what's going wrong when I am using a similar concept show the text in the children (i.e. "li") of the tag "ul".
Gramercy...

Comment: That's because when you do `var no=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; var msg=no.firstChild.nodeValue` firstChild is actually a textnode, not an element, while if you select an element, you have to use `textContent`.

Comment: Thanx for your reply....I am still a bit confused. In my code which I presented above, var no=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; means variable "no" has the element "ul". Variable "son" has the children of no, i.e. the children "ul", i.e. "li". "li"'s first child is again text. Hence, nodeValue should return text....If you are all confused what I am trying to say, it would be very kind of you to tell me how I can access the text inside "li" using nodeValue, (but not textContent)...
Gramercy...

Comment: Well, yes, except when you come to the LI that has an anhcor inside it, then it's no longer a textnode but an anchor, hence an element. `textContent` works with both the textnodes and the anchor.

Comment: True, but how do I access the text "List 1" which does not have an anchor associated...?
Gramercy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `childNodes` use `children` 
So, it should be.

```
var son=no.children;
```

Your JS:

```
var son=no.children;
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<son.length;i++){

          msg+=son[i].firstChild.nodeValue;


        }
```

> Why not working?

[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them, use [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.

Comment: Thanx...it worked! But I still don't understand why childNodes was not working. I wanted text nodes and comments to be included. But, it was simply returning null...
Gramercy...

Comment: childNodes returns text nodes which dont have nodeValue.So,you getting exception and script stop execution